# How to resize image as part of an html editor extender ajax file upload event

Tags: content-management-system, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the image upload working and saving to a folder on the webserver. I need to resize the image before uploading, but how do I get ahold of the byte array before the ajax control toolkit uploader starts the upload process. I know I have to override the control, where do I hook into the upload event? Thanks in advance.

I have the code to call out to a method to do the resizing; so I want to return the byte array back to the upload event.

After working on Yuriy's answer.

I recompiled the control toolkit after adding the code outlined in the answer. I can add the 3 properties to the HtmlEditorExtender instance. The code that saves the image resides in the OnUploadCompleted event, but is not calling the resize code in the HtmlEditorExtender.cs file. Using JustDecomplie, I can see the dll has the changes in the re-compiled toolkit. I re-added the toolkit to the VS 2012 toolbox and re-created the reference to the dll. I know I am close to getting this new functionality working, but I was hoping for another helping hand in getting the resize function working.

```
protected void ajaxFileUpload_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ContentType.Contains("jpg") || e.ContentType.Contains("gif")
        || e.ContentType.Contains("png") || e.ContentType.Contains("jpeg"))
    {
        Session["fileContentType_" + e.FileId] = e.ContentType;
        Session["fileContents_" + e.FileId] = e.GetContents();
    }

    string fullPath = "/ExtenderImages/" + e.FileName;

    // Save your File
    HtmlEditorExtender1.AjaxFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fullPath));

    e.PostedUrl = fullPath;
}
```

Comment: thanks, Yuriy. I will be working on your answer soon. Hope to get back with upvotes soon. Robert

Comment: still learning how to present code blocks, sorry for the newbie appearance.

Comment: I am assuming that the resize methods live in the HtmlEditorExtender.cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download AjaxControlToolkit sources and customize the `Server/AjaxControlToolkit/HtmlEditorExtender/HtmlEditorExtender.cs` file. Add properties below to the HtmlEditorExtender class:

```
[Browsable(true)]
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool ResizeUploadedImages { get; set; }

[Browsable(true)]
[DefaultValue(int.MaxValue)]
public int UploadedImageMaxWidth { get; set; }

[Browsable(true)]
[DefaultValue(int.MaxValue)]
public int UploadedImageMaxHeight { get; set; }
```

Also, fix the OnInit method as below:

```
/// <summary>
/// On Init add popup div and ajaxfileupload control to support Add image
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">Event Arguments</param>
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    if (!DesignMode)
    {
        // Check if EnableSanitization is enabled and sanitizer provider is not configured.
        if (EnableSanitization && sanitizerProvider == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Sanitizer provider is not configured in the web.config file. If you are using the HtmlEditorExtender with a public website then please configure a Sanitizer provider. Otherwise, set the EnableSanitization property to false.");
        }

        HtmlGenericControl popupdiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        popupdiv.Attributes.Add("Id", this.ClientID + "_popupDiv");
        popupdiv.Attributes.Add("style", "opacity: 0;");
        popupdiv.Attributes.Add("class", "popupDiv");

        ajaxFileUpload = new AjaxFileUpload();
        ajaxFileUpload.ID = this.ID + "_ajaxFileUpload";
        ajaxFileUpload.MaximumNumberOfFiles = 10;
        ajaxFileUpload.AllowedFileTypes = "jpg,jpeg,gif,png";
        ajaxFileUpload.Enabled = true;
        ajaxFileUpload.OnClientUploadComplete = "ajaxClientUploadComplete";

        if(ResizeUploadedImages)
        {
            ajaxFileUpload.UploadComplete += (sender, args) =>
                                                    {
                                                        var content = args.GetContents();
                                                        var resized = ResizeImage(content, UploadedImageMaxWidth, UploadedImageMaxHeight);
                                                        args.SetContents(resized);
                                                    };
        }

        if (ImageUploadComplete != null)
        {
            ajaxFileUpload.UploadComplete += ImageUploadComplete;
        }
        popupdiv.Controls.Add(ajaxFileUpload);

        HtmlGenericControl btnCancel = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        btnCancel.Attributes.Add("Id", this.ClientID + "_btnCancel");
        btnCancel.Attributes.Add("style", "float: right; position:relative; padding-left: 20px; top:10px; width: 55px; border-color:black;border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;cursor:pointer;");
        btnCancel.Attributes.Add("float", "right");
        btnCancel.Attributes.Add("unselectable", "on");
        btnCancel.InnerText = "Cancel";
        popupdiv.Controls.Add(btnCancel);

        this.Controls.Add(popupdiv);
    }
}
```

I used this code for image resizing:

```
private byte[] ResizeImage(byte[] imageBytes, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
    {
        return ResizeImage(memStream, maxWidth, maxHeight);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Resizes images to the specified size.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="imageStream">The file stream.</param>
/// <param name="maxWidth">Maximum Width</param>
/// <param name="maxHeight">Maximum Height</param>
private byte[] ResizeImage(System.IO.Stream imageStream, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    byte[] result;
    try
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap originalBMP = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imageStream))
        {
            // Calculate the new image dimensions
            int width = originalBMP.Width; //actual width
            int height = originalBMP.Height; //actual height
            int widthDiff = (width - maxWidth); //how far off maxWidth?
            int heightDiff = (height - maxHeight); //how far off maxHeight?

            //figure out which dimension is further outside the max size
            bool doWidthResize = (maxWidth > 0 && width > maxWidth && widthDiff > -1 && (widthDiff > heightDiff || maxHeight.Equals(0)));
            bool doHeightResize = (maxHeight > 0 && height > maxHeight && heightDiff > -1 && (heightDiff > widthDiff || maxWidth.Equals(0)));

            //only resize if the image is bigger than the max or where image is square, and the diffs are the same
            if (doWidthResize || doHeightResize || (width.Equals(height) && widthDiff.Equals(heightDiff)))
            {
                int iStart;
                Decimal divider;
                if (doWidthResize)
                {
                    iStart = width;
                    divider = Math.Abs((Decimal)iStart / (Decimal)maxWidth);
                    width = maxWidth;
                    height = (int)Math.Round((Decimal)(height / divider));
                }
                else
                {
                    iStart = height;
                    divider = Math.Abs((Decimal)iStart / (Decimal)maxHeight);
                    height = maxHeight;
                    width = (int)Math.Round((Decimal)(width / divider));
                }
            }

            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap newBMP = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(originalBMP, width, height))
            {
                using (System.Drawing.Graphics oGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newBMP))
                {
                    oGraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    oGraphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, width, height);
                    oGraphics.Save();
                }

                result = (new ImageConverter()).ConvertTo(newBMP, typeof(byte[])) as byte[];
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        result = null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

BTW, also you must to change the `Server/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUploadEventArgs` file to allow changing uploaded file content: you need to add `SetContents` method as below:

```
internal void SetContents(byte[] value)
{
    _contents = value;
}
```

Comment: resize code is not working. I built an image resizer app for my clients to build an image library of various sizes for uploading to the webserver. thanks for the resize code and the logic of determining sizes and math to calculate final sizes. My project is moving along with progress again. thank you.